# THREE.js rotation on loaded file

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been playing around with this ThreeJS library for a couple of weeks now, and using inspiration from others, I've made a canvas that displays an external .stl-file.

My only problem is I can't seem to apply any transformations to it. I can move the camera around just fine, but I can't get even the most simple transformations to work. I'm not best with JavaScript, so I might have missed some essential parts.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>three.js webgl - STL</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>

  <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
  <script src="dat.gui.js"></script>

  <script>

   if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

   var container;
   var rotationSpeed;
   var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;

   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 15 );
    camera.position.set( -3, 1, 3 );

    cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x72645b, 2, 15 );


    // Ground

    var plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 40, 40 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x999999, color: 0x999999, specular: 0x101010 } ) );
    plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
    plane.position.y = -0.5;
    scene.add( plane );

    plane.receiveShadow = true;


    // ASCII file

    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

     var geometry = event.content;
     var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0xff5533, color: 0xff5533, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
     var model = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

     model.position.set( 0, 0.05, 0 );
     model.rotation.set( Math.PI / 2.0, - Math.PI / 1.5, 0 );
     model.scale.set( 0.01, 0.01, 0.01 );

     model.castShadow = true;
     model.receiveShadow = true;

     scene.add( model );

    } );
    loader.load( './models/stl/ascii/cover.stl' );


    // Lights

    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x777777 ) );

    addShadowedLight( 1, 1, 1, 0xffffff, 1.35 );
    addShadowedLight( 0.5, 1, -1, 0xffaa00, 1 );

    // renderer

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );

    renderer.gammaInput = true;
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;

    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

   }

   function addShadowedLight( x, y, z, color, intensity ) {

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( color, intensity );
    directionalLight.position.set( x, y, z )
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    // directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;

    var d = 1;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraRight = d;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraTop = d;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

    directionalLight.shadowCameraNear = 1;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraFar = 4;

    directionalLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
    directionalLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

    directionalLight.shadowBias = -0.005;
    directionalLight.shadowDarkness = 0.15;

   }
/*   var controls = new function()
   {
    this.rotationSpeed = 0.2;
   }

   var gui = new dat.GUI();
   gui.add(controls, 'rotationSpeed',0,1);
*/   
   function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

   }

   function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

   }

   function render() {

    var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;


    camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );

                //THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
                //model.position.x = Math.cos( timer );
                //model.position.z = Math.sin( timer );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

   }

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The last lines before the render() function just gives me a black, blank page.
Even things like model.position.x += 0.02; kills it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the mistake here , but sorry some how not able to port your code to JSFIDDLE

Here is the problem I found,

model variable is not declared in the global scope. It is initialized locally in the init() function and you are trying the manipulate that variable with in the render function, where it does not have any scope.

So the solution is Just declare the variable model before calling the init() function just like other variables that you are declaring there by adding this below line.

```
var model;
```

Comment: What a rookie mistake. Thank you. Did not have enough reputation to upvote you before now

Comment: @LaughingMan, Thanks for confirming it :)